# GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?

Tags: java, android, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON string like this one

```
[
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 21:06:01",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"JOHN",
      "url":"http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f4791da203d0c2d76000035",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"
   },
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 14:07:44",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"PETER",
      "url":"http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f476f61203d0c2d89000253",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"
   }
]
```

into a list of objects.

```
List<ChannelSearchEnum> lcs = (List<ChannelSearchEnum>) new Gson().fromJson( jstring , ChannelSearchEnum.class);
```

Here's an object class I'm using.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ChannelSearchEnum {



@SerializedName("updated_at")
private String updated_at;

@SerializedName("fetched_at")
private String fetched_at;

@SerializedName("description")
private String description;

@SerializedName("language")
private String language;

@SerializedName("title")
private String title;

@SerializedName("url")
private String url;

@SerializedName("icon_url")
private String icon_url;

@SerializedName("logo_url")
private String logo_url;

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("modified")
private String modified;

public final String get_Updated_at() {
    return this.updated_at;
}

public final String get_Fetched_at() {
    return this.fetched_at;
}

public final String get_Description() {
    return this.description;
}

public final String get_Language() {
    return this.language;
}

public final String get_Title() {
    return this.title;
}

public final String get_Url() {
    return this.url;
}

public final String get_Icon_url() {
    return this.icon_url;
}

public final String get_Logo_url() {
    return this.logo_url;
}

public final String get_Id() {
    return this.id;
}

public final String get_Modified() {
    return this.modified;
}

        }
```

But it throws me with

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

Any ideas how should I fix it?

Comment: @Soni - that is incorrect. If you go to jsonlint.org and copy/paste his JSON you will see that it is valid.

Comment: @Soni - nope, removed "[" and "]", but still the same. guess it might be more because the string I have contains multiple objects, not just one.

Comment: What does your `jstring` look like that you alluded to in your code?

Comment: i observe one think , when response return in array then try to take in List ,it's solve my problem .

Comment: Also, please check if your API Interface has the correct return type. This happens when you are expecting a List but have an Object defined as the return type.

Answer (score 385, accepted):

The problem is you're telling `Gson` you have an object of your type. You don't. You have an array of objects of your type. You can't just try and cast the result like that and expect it to magically work ;)

The User guide for `Gson` Explains how to deal with this:

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

This will work:

```
ChannelSearchEnum[] enums = gson.fromJson(yourJson, ChannelSearchEnum[].class);
```

But this is better:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ChannelSearchEnum>>(){}.getType();
Collection<ChannelSearchEnum> enums = gson.fromJson(yourJson, collectionType);
```

Comment: probably indeed. as an array of object, the type is retained at runtime so gson knows what to look for. good idea.

Comment: +1 for the `TypoToken<Collection<Something>>` -- don't use arrays when you can have Collection (subclasses) and/or Iterables.

Comment: Do you think it is the right method to parse selected obj/array? help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140830/gson-throwing-expected-expected-a-name-but-was-number-at-line-1-column-8

Comment: What if we want to make it with string; For example
     can I write something like String[] t = gson.fromJson(myJson,String[].class)

Comment: what sort of Type is that? what to import?

Comment: Where is your `enums` used??  I don't get it.

Comment: Feeling this answer is unfinished!!

Comment: For Kotlin: TypeToken<List< ChannelSearchEnum >>(){}.type

Answer (score 57):

The problem is that you are asking for an object of type `ChannelSearchEnum` but what you actually have is an object of type `List<ChannelSearchEnum>`.

You can achieve this with:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<ChannelSearchEnum>>(){}.getType();
List<ChannelSearchEnum> lcs = (List<ChannelSearchEnum>) new Gson()
               .fromJson( jstring , collectionType);
```

Comment: what sort of `Type` is that? what to import?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English most likely `java.lang.reflect.Type`

Answer (score 50):

In my case JSON string:

```
[{"category":"College Affordability",
  "uid":"150151",
  "body":"Ended more than $60 billion in wasteful subsidies for big banks and used the savings to put the cost of college within reach for more families.",
  "url":"http:\/\/www.whitehouse.gov\/economy\/middle-class\/helping middle-class-families-pay-for-college",
  "url_title":"ending subsidies for student loan lenders",
  "type":"Progress",
  "path":"node\/150385"}]
```

and I print "category" and "url_title" in recycleview

Datum.class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {
@SerializedName("category")
@Expose
private String category;
@SerializedName("uid")
@Expose
private String uid;
@SerializedName("url_title")
@Expose
private String urlTitle;

/**
 * @return The category
 */
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

/**
 * @param category The category
 */
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

/**
 * @return The uid
 */
public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

/**
 * @param uid The uid
 */
public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

/**
 * @return The urlTitle
 */
public String getUrlTitle() {
    return urlTitle;
}

/**
 * @param urlTitle The url_title
 */
public void setUrlTitle(String urlTitle) {
    this.urlTitle = urlTitle;
}

}
```

RequestInterface

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

/**
 * Created by Shweta.Chauhan on 13/07/16.
 */

public interface RequestInterface {

   @GET("facts/json/progress/all")
   Call<List<Datum>> getJSON();
}
```

DataAdapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shweta.Chauhan on 13/07/16.
 */

public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private List<Datum> dataList;

public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Datum> dataList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.data,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.categoryTV.setText(dataList.get(position).getCategory());
    holder.urltitleTV.setText(dataList.get(position).getUrlTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView categoryTV, urltitleTV;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_category);
        urltitleTV = (TextView)     itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_urltitle);
    }
}
}
```

and finally MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
private List<Datum> dataArrayList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}

private void initViews(){
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    loadJSON();
}

private void loadJSON(){
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://www.whitehouse.gov/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    RequestInterface requestInterface=retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<List<Datum>> call= requestInterface.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Datum>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Datum>> call, Response<List<Datum>> response) {
            dataArrayList = response.body();
            dataAdapter=new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),dataArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Datum>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: best answer for such type of problem

Comment: This perfectly answers the question especially for retrofit users. For anyone who seeks clarity, the part you need most is  Call<List<Datum>> getJSON();

Comment: can you perform the same task with coroutines??

Answer (score 17):

Alternative could be

to make your response look like

**myCustom_JSONResponse**

```
{"master":[
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 21:06:01",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"JOHN",
      "url":"http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f4791da203d0c2d76000035",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"
   },
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 14:07:44",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"PETER",
      "url":"http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f476f61203d0c2d89000253",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"
   }
]
}
```

instead of

**server_JSONResponse**

```
[
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 21:06:01",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.728840",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"JOHN",
      "url":"http://rus.JOHN.JOHN/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f4791da203d0c2d76000035",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:58.840076"
   },
   {
      "updated_at":"2012-03-02 14:07:44",
      "fetched_at":"2012-03-02 21:28:37.033108",
      "description":null,
      "language":null,
      "title":"PETER",
      "url":"http://PETER.PETER.lv/rss.php",
      "icon_url":null,
      "logo_url":null,
      "id":"4f476f61203d0c2d89000253",
      "modified":"2012-03-02 23:28:57.928001"
   }
]
```

**CODE**

```
  String server_JSONResponse =.... // the string in which you are getting your JSON Response after hitting URL
String myCustom_JSONResponse="";// in which we will keep our response after adding object element to it
     MyClass apiResponse = new MyClass();

     myCustom_JSONResponse="{\"master\":"+server_JSONResponse+"}";



    apiResponse = gson.fromJson(myCustom_JSONResponse, MyClass .class);
```

After this it will be just any other `GSON Parsing`

Comment: what if i am not able to change my json format? I am using volley's gson request to set my model class. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal try other solutions provided in this thread, other than this I have no idea

Answer (score 11):

This looks like a Json array list.Therefore its best to use `ArrayList` to handle the data. In your api end point add array list like this

```
 @GET("places/")
Call<ArrayList<Place>> getNearbyPlaces(@Query("latitude") String latitude, @Query("longitude") String longitude);
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding ArrayList solve my problem. Thanks a lot !
Most effective answer. This should be mark as best answer.

Answer (score 8):

according to [GSON User guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples), you cannot.

> **Collections Limitations**
>
> Can serialize collection of arbitrary objects but can not deserialize from it. Because there is no way for the user to indicate the type of the resulting object

Comment: He doesn't have an collection of arbitrary objects, he has a collection of *one specific* type of object which `Gson` will happily deal with

Comment: actually, i started by writing an answer with the TypeToken just as you did, but since the generic type is not embedded at runtime, i didn't see how that could possibly work. (though i haven't tested it).

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin:

```
var list=ArrayList<Your class name>()
val listresult: Array<YOUR CLASS NAME> = Gson().fromJson(
                YOUR JSON RESPONSE IN STRING,
                Array<Your class name>:: class.java)

list.addAll(listresult)
```

Comment: I did not upvote or downvote anything, only edited.

Comment: Thank you verymuch ! Because the java solution doesnt work in kotlin. List does work in java, but it's Array in kotlin...

Answer (score 5):

You need to let Gson know additional type of your response as below

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;


Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<UserSite>>(){}.getType();
List<UserSite> userSites  = gson.fromJson( response.getBody() , collectionType);
```

Comment: Addition:  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best way to use GSON, but works for me. You can use some like this on the `MainActivity`:

```
 public void readJson() {
    dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String json = "[\n" + IOHelper.getData(this) + "\n]\n";
    Log.d(TAG, json);
    try{
        JSONArray channelSearchEnums = new JSONArray(json);

        for(int i=0; i< channelSearchEnums.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject enum = channelSearchEnums.getJSONObject(i);
            ChannelSearchEnum channel = new ChannelSearchEnum(
                   enum.getString("updated_at"), enum.getString("fetched_at"),
                   enum.getString("description"), enum.getString("language"),
                   enum.getString("title"), enum.getString("url"),
                   enum.getString("icon_url"), enum.getString("logo_url"),
                   enum.getString("id"), enum.getString("modified"))         

                   dataArrayList.add(channel);
        }

         //The code and place you want to show your data            

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

You only have strings, but if you would have doubles or int, you could put `getDouble` or `getInt` too.

The method of `IOHelper` class is the next (Here, the path is save on the internal Storage):

```
 public static String getData(Context context) {
    try {
        File f = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + fileName);
        //check whether file exists
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        return new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Reading: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want more information about this, you can see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYQSkadfa4k), where I get the code of `readJson()`; and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219253/writing-json-file-and-read-that-file-in-android) where I get the code of `getData()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ChannelSearchEnum[] getChannelSearchEnum(Response response) {
        return response.as(ChannelSearchEnum[].class, ObjectMapperType.GSON);
}
```

Above will solve and passing response will returned mapped object array of the class

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. I am using volley library. I parse response automatic in volley using GSON

```json
    [
            {
                "name": "Naruto: Shippuuden",
                "description": "It has been two and a half years since Naruto Uzumaki left Konohagakure, the Hidden Leaf Village, for intense training following events which fueled his desire to be stronger. Now Akatsuki, the mysterious organization of elite rogue ninja, is closing in on their grand plan which may threaten the safety of the entire shinobi world.",
                "Rating": "8.16",
                "episode": 500,
                "categorie":"Animation | Drama | Adventure",
                "studio":"Studio Pierrot",
                "img": "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/5/17407.jpg"
            },
            {
                "name": "One Piece",
                "description": "Gol D. Roger was known as the 'Pirate King',the strongest and most infamous being to have sailed the Grand Line. The capture and death of Roger by the World Government brought a change throughout the world. His last words before his death revealed the existence of the greatest treasure in the world, One Piece. It was this revelation that brought about the Grand Age of Pirates, men who dreamed of finding One Piece—which promises an unlimited amount of riches and fame—and quite possibly the pinnacle of glory and the title of the Pirate King.",
                "Rating": "8.54",
                "episode": 700,
                 "categorie":"Animation | Drama | Adventure",
                "studio":"Toei Animation",
                "img": "https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/6/73245.jpg"
            }
        ]
```

2.This my model

```java
    public class DataResponse implements Serializable {
    
        @SerializedName("studio")
        private String studio;
    
        @SerializedName("img")
        private String img;
    
        @SerializedName("categorie")
        private String categorie;
    
        @SerializedName("Rating")
        private String rating;
    
        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;
    
        @SerializedName("description")
        private String description;
    
        @SerializedName("episode")
        private int episode;
    
        public void setStudio(String studio){
            this.studio = studio;
        }
    
        public String getStudio(){
            return studio;
        }
    
        public void setImg(String img){
            this.img = img;
        }
    
        public String getImg(){
            return img;
        }
    
        public void setCategorie(String categorie){
            this.categorie = categorie;
        }
    
        public String getCategorie(){
            return categorie;
        }
    
        public void setRating(String rating){
            this.rating = rating;
        }
    
        public String getRating(){
            return rating;
        }
    
        public void setName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }
    
        public void setDescription(String description){
            this.description = description;
        }
    
        public String getDescription(){
            return description;
        }
    
        public void setEpisode(int episode){
            this.episode = episode;
        }
    
        public int getEpisode(){
            return episode;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return 
                "Response{" + 
                "studio = '" + studio + '\'' + 
                ",img = '" + img + '\'' + 
                ",categorie = '" + categorie + '\'' + 
                ",rating = '" + rating + '\'' + 
                ",name = '" + name + '\'' + 
                ",description = '" + description + '\'' + 
                ",episode = '" + episode + '\'' + 
                "}";
            }
    }
```

3. my api method

```
define globle

private List<DataResponse> dataResponses = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
    private void volleyAutomation(String url) {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            JsonArrayRequest request_json = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, array,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    
                            GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                            Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                           dataResponses = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response.toString(), DataResponse[].class));
    
                            rvList(dataResponses);
                            Log.d("respknce___", String.valueOf(dataResponses.size()));
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    
                }
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(request_json);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

receive the returning response in the model class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).