# Android : Error in parsing JSON array using GSON library

Tags: android, json, gson, android-parser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GSON throwing “Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

**Scenario :** I am parsing an API which is is JSON format using GSON library. Here the JSON file I am parsing :

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "question_1": "Question 1",
      "options": [
        "option_1 : option1",
        "option_2 : option2",
        "option_3 : option 3",
        "option_4 : option 4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "question_2": "Question 2",
      "options": [
        "option_1 : option 1",
        "option_2 : option 2",
        "option_3 : option 3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**And my object class looks like this :**

```
public class Practise_Question_Object {

    public List<Questions> questions;

    public class Questions {

        @SerializedName("question")
        public String Question;

        public List<Options> options;

        public class Options {

            public String Option_1;

            public String Option_2;

            public String Option_3;

            public String Option_4;
        }

    }
```

**Problem**
My problem is that whenever I try to parse values It show me error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 53`

if I chagne "options" from Array to Object then I can easily parse. But in my project (From PHP side) i cant use Object.

Comment: are you want to pass this json to the server?

Comment: No I want to parse this JSON from the server.

Comment: In PHP, associative arrays are encoded as objects in JSON... you can't use associative arrays? (there is only one type of arrays in PHP anyway). Create a proper representation of your data, it seems you don't want an array there anyways.

Comment: @QVDev : No my problem is different.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with GSON, but your Java class does not seem to match your JSON. You tell GSON that `options` is an array of `Options` objects, where each `Option` has 4 string attributes. But that is not the case, `options` is an array of 4 strings. I could be totally wrong though...

Comment: But I don't know how to tell GSON to get "options" from the JSON.
How do I get 4 strings from "option" array?

Comment: `public List<String> options;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change this line:

```
public List<Options> options;
```

to:

```
public Options[] options;
```

It looks like your JSON contains an array of `Options` objects.

---

Otherwise can I suggest posting the actual code you use in the web service, just to confirm that you are using the GSOM DOM-style automatic parsing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used **public String[] options;** instead of **public Options[] options;** and my problem is solved. Great answer. Thanks again.