# JSON String to Java object using GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to parse json to java.

I have the following string that is valid json according to jsonlint.com

```
private final static String LOC_JSON = 
         "["
        +"{"
        +"  \"lat1\": 39.737567,"
        +"  \"lat2\": 32.7801399,"
        +"  \"long1\": -104.98471790000002,"
        +"  \"long2\": -96.80045109999998"
        +"},"
        +"  ["
        +"      {"
        +"          \"lat\": {"
        +"              \"b\": 38.88368709500021,"
        +"              \"d\": 40.620468491667026"
        +"          },"
        +"          \"long\": {"
        +"          \"b\": -105.75306170749764,"
        +"          \"d\": -104.675854661387"
        +"          }"
        +"      }"
        +"  ]"
        +"]";
```

I am trying to parse it into an object and I get the following error.
"Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2"

```
            Gson gson = new Gson();
        BoxSearch b = gson.fromJson( LOC_JSON, BoxSearch.class );
```

BoxSearch consists of this.

```
private Number lat1;
private Number lat2;
private Number long1;
private Number long2;
private Boxes[] boxes;
```

Boxes is a Latitude object and a Longitude object which are both defined identical.

```
private String b;
private String d;
```

I can parse the higher level attributes (lat1,lat2,long1 and long2) into a more simple BoxSearch object that only has those 4 attributes. The trouble comes when the json and the object are more complex. Is it even possible to do what I am trying?

I hope I have provided enough information to get some help. I would be happy to provide more info or even a test project if need be. I am running this as a junit test.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) - your JSON is an array, not an object. You are going to have a problem though because it's an array containing different types of objects (an object and an array) which you can not deal with without writing a custom deserializer

Comment: @BrianRoach this is more like an answer ;)

Comment: @RC. Yeah ... Hmm. I think maybe I'll move it, the old Q answers why he's getting the error, but the resolution to his case is different

Comment: I did go through the possible duplicate but that object is simple as opposed to complex. Is there a better way to organize the json string? My UI is putting it together (based on google maps) but I can manipulate it. I guess I will try more simple/flatter object. Or is writing a custom deserializer the way to go?

Comment: @user2415153 - see my extended answer below. If you're the one generating the JSON, then yes - redoing that so it's an object rather than an array will make your life much easier. Let me expand on that a bit in my answer; editing.

Comment: @user2415153 see final editing of my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your JSON at the top level is an array, not an object. That is covered by [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array).

However, the solution there won't work for your JSON because you have an array of mixed types (an object and an array) rather than an array of a single type of object. For that you're going to have to write a custom deserializer (See [The section of the Gson user's guide that covers this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types)) or use Gson's [`JsonParser`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) class directly and extract the data from the parse tree.

**Edit from comments above:**

If you're the one creating the JSON, it *looks* like what you want is an array of `BoxSearch` objects?

Based on your Java `BoxSearch` class, you'd need JSON structured like:

```
[
    {
        "lat1" : 39.737567,
        "lat2" : 32.7801399,
        "long1" : -104.98471790000002,
        "long2" : -96.80045109999998,
        "boxes" : [ 
                    {
                      "lat": {
                          "b": 38.88368709500021,
                          "d": 40.620468491667026
                      },
                      "long": {
                          "b": -105.75306170749764,
                          "d": -104.675854661387
                      }
                    }
                  ]
    }
]
```

However, the way you have `Boxes` class defined won't work for that. (Did you mean to have an array of them?). As-is it would need to look like:

```
class Boxes {
    Box lat;
    @SerializedName("long")
    Box lon;
}

class Box {
   String b;
   String d;
}
```

Now you have an array containing one type of object (`BoxSearch`) which you could deserialize with:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<BoxSearch>>(){}.getType();
Collection<BoxSearch> boxSearchCollection = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

If you really don't need an array of these, get rid of the outer array and simply do:

```
gson.fromJson(json, BoxSearch.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, that slight tweak to the json and all is well. I would vote this answer up but I have no "street cred". The code works like a champ. In case people copy and paste this answer, Box long; needs to be renamed :-)

Comment: Oh and yes I needed the array. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2415153 I changed the code so it'll work with `"long"` in the JSON - see the answer now :) I didn't notice that, sorry. As for upvoting - you can accept my answer ;) and glad I could help!

Comment: Fancy solution! I just renamed the variables to the full words. Accepting as answered! Thanks again!

Answer (score 33):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(jsonStr,YourClass.class);
```

very easy.

Comment: it help me to convert a json object that have a list inside. I convert the json string to Object.class