# how to parse simple json string array to object in java

Tags: java

I have a json array as a string in the following format:

```
 [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

which is a legal json string. How am I able to use Gson to save into an object? 
When I am trying to use getAsJsonArray(), but I get an error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: This is not a JSON Array.
```

Comment: Add your code and the complete stacktrace

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780576/parsing-json-array-resulting-in-this-is-not-a-json-array-exception it might help guide you

Comment: take a look at this site : http://www.javatpoint.com/json-array    and this : http://www.json.org/index.html

Comment: `JsonArray jArray = new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonArray();` works fine for me. If you got that exception this means that you are not parsing what you expect. Post proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Comment: I have added an example. I am unsure if this is what you are actually looking for? My solution it into String object since you only mentioned `an object`. Your question is vague, what object do you want to save it to?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Gson` to parse your Json array.

```
String input = "[ 'Ford', 'BMW', 'Fiat' ]";

Gson gson = new Gson();
String[] output = gson.fromJson(input, String[].class);

for(String s : output){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output**

```
Ford
BMW
Fiat
```

Comment: Thrown exception suggests that OP is not parsing valid JSON array, but what was posted in question is valid which suggests that problem is not *how* OP is parsing, but *what*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get value into arraylist using getAsJsonArray() Method

```
    String jsonStr = "['Ford', 'BMW', 'Fiat' ]";
    JsonArray root = new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonArray();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ArrayList<String> staff = new ArrayList<>() ;
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
    List<String> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(root, listType);

    System.out.println(yourList );
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary things