# how to read JsonElement ? "This is not a JSON Array."

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have JsonElement like this:

```
{
    "76800769": {
        "prosjekLat": 45.784661646364,
        "prosjekLong": 15.947804310909,
        "brojCelija": 11
    },
    "76800772": {
        "prosjekLat": 45.7847808175,
        "prosjekLong": 15.9477082775,
        "brojCelija": 4
    },
    "2946694": {
        "prosjekLat": 45.78475167,
        "prosjekLong": 15.9475975,
        "brojCelija": 1
    },
    "76829440": {
        "prosjekLat": 45.784726386,
        "prosjekLong": 15.947961766,
        "brojCelija": 5
    }
}
```

I also create Model:

```
public class AddMarker {    
    int cellId;    
    double longitude;    
    double latitude;
}
```

I want to read JSON file and put values to `List<AddMarker>`.

I'm trying with this:

```
JsonElement data = response.body();
                JsonObject obj = data.getAsJsonObject();
                JsonArray arr = obj.getAsJsonArray();
```

but I'm getting an err: "This is not a JSON Array."

Comment: `{...}` is object, `[...]` is array,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing Json Array resulting in This is not a JSON Array exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780576/parsing-json-array-resulting-in-this-is-not-a-json-array-exception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not an array.

[Json Array syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_json_arrays.asp) dictates that in order to have an array, your object must be formatted as:

```
[
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

Right now you have the outer square brackets (`[]`) as curly braces (`{}`). Change it to square brackets and your code should run correctly.

Comment: It work !! i just use " json_encode(array_values($izracunatProsjek), true); " instead of " json_encode($izracunatProsjek, true); " .

Comment: @GoranBelačić Yup, that'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to make a array from a single object: JsonArray arr = obj.getAsJsonArray(), where obj is for exemple just this :
"76829440": {
        "prosjekLat": 45.784726386,
        "prosjekLong": 15.947961766,
        "brojCelija": 5
    }

you need to get the body from the response and make an array with all these objects, not from a single one

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject(data);
String str1 = json.getString("76800769");
JsonObject json2 = new JsonObject(str1);
float str11 = json2.getFloat("prosjekLat");
```

Comment: You should probably explain *why* OP should use your solution, rather than supplying just code

Answer (score 0):

Using **org.json** liberary, you can read the element as follows:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("your json element");
JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject) obj.get("76800769");

System.out.println(obj2.get("brojCelija"));
System.out.println(obj2.get("prosjekLat"));
System.out.println(obj2.get("prosjekLong"));
```

which gives below output:

> 11 
>  
>   45.784661646364
>   15.947804310909

Answer (score 0):

I need to convert JSON Object to array. In php just use array_values( $json ).
I solve my problem using this:

```
json_encode(array_values($izracunatProsjek), true);
```