# Gson throws "BEGIN_OBJECT expected but BEGIN_ARRAY found" - how to use TypeToken

Tags: android, json, gson

Trying out Gson for the first time instead of looping through the JSON objects for speed.

This is my input data set for parsing

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "XXXXX", 
      "category": "Community", 
      "name": "Startup notes by Vrashabh", 
      "id": "XXXXX", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "access_token": "XXXX", 
      "category": "Community", 
      "name": "Clean Bangalore", 
      "id": "XXXXX", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "access_token": "XXXXX", 
      "category": "Internet/software", 
      "name": "Getmeetin", 
      "id": "XXXXX", 
      "perms": [
        "ADMINISTER", 
        "EDIT_PROFILE", 
        "CREATE_CONTENT", 
        "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
        "CREATE_ADS", 
        "BASIC_ADMIN"
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTU3MzE3MTA0MjkyMjY4MQ==", 
      "after": "MjcyMTIwMzE2Mjk3NzI5"
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my gson mapping class

```
public class AccountsResponse {
    ArrayList<AcResponseData> data;
    ArrayList<PagingData> paging;

    public class AcResponseData {
        public String access_token;
        public String category;
        public String name;
        public String id;
        public String[] perms;
    }
    public class PagingData{
        public Cursors cursors;
    }
    public class Cursors{
        public String before;
        public String after;
    }
}
```

Code for parsing the data

```
AccountsResponse responseAccounts = gsonResponse.fromJson(response.getRawResponse(), AccountsResponse.class);
```

I Know I am supposed to not expect magic in terms of data conversion, I found the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array) questions on SO that ask me to implement TypeToken but I couldn't get it working for this case.  How do I use TypeToken to get this data into the ORM
I wouldn't mind not reading that paging data also actually, if that needs to be eliminated from the ORM

**UPDATE**
Changed the ORM as below but now I get

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using to parse the JSON data?

Comment: I've just Added That

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `AccountsResponse` class. It should be an object `PagingData` not an `ArrayList`, because from the json response in your question, "paging" is a JSON object not a JSON array. So, you should declare `paging` as a `PagingData` object not as an `ArrayList` of `PagingData` objects. That should fix it.

```
public class AccountsResponse {
    ArrayList<AcResponseData> data;
    PagingData paging;

    public class AcResponseData {
        public String access_token;
        public String category;
        public String name;
        public String id;
        public String[] perms;
    }
    public class PagingData{
        public Cursors cursors;
    }
    public class Cursors{
        public String before;
        public String after;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes I figured that out :) Thanks!

Comment: well unfortunately/ironically now I'm getting java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: I suppose that happens if there is a circular reference, but I dont see any in the data

Comment: Marking this correct, solved my original problem anyway, will open a new question for a follow up problem