# Verbose exception messages from gson?

Tags: java, json, debugging, gson

I'm trying to parse a big chunk of JSON with gson (assisted by GsonFire).  Somewhere along the way it's throwing a `JsonSyntaxException`.

I know what the exception means, but I'm parsing a huge file and it would really help if I could figure out *which* token is causing the exception.  Is there a way to get more verbose output from gson?

Exception is below:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:281)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.deserialize(FireTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.read(FireTypeAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:281)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.deserialize(FireTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.read(FireTypeAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:281)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.deserialize(FireTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.read(FireTypeAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:281)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.deserialize(FireTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.read(FireTypeAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.TypeAdapter.fromJsonTree(TypeAdapter.java:281)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.deserialize(FireTypeAdapter.java:93)
    at io.gsonfire.gson.FireTypeAdapter.read(FireTypeAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
    at com.inin.util.BinarySerializable.fromJsonFile(BinarySerializable.java:90)
    at com.inin.util.BinarySerializable.fromJsonFile(BinarySerializable.java:83)
    at com.inin.simulation.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.expect(JsonTreeReader.java:139)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeReader.beginObject(JsonTreeReader.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: Have you looked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: @ema Yes.  I have already solved the problem that initially caused the exception, but this question is about how to get more information about future errors from gson. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Gson 2.3](https://publicobject.com/2014/08/12/gson-2-3-and-why-you-want-it/), you get a much nicer exception. It tells you the JSONPath to the failure, for example:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a boolean but was NUMBER at line 1 column 4728 path $.history[0].change_status.deletions  
  at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextBoolean()
  at com.google.gson.TypeAdapters$3.read()
  at com.google.gson.TypeAdapters$3.read()
  at com.google.gson.ReflectiveTypeAdapter$1.read()
  at com.google.gson.ReflectiveTypeAdapter$Adapter.read()
  at com.google.gson.ReflectiveTypeAdapter$Adapter.read()
  at com.google.gson.ReflectiveTypeAdapter$1.read()
  at com.google.gson.ReflectiveTypeAdapter$Adapter.read()
  ...
```