# How to parse JSON with nested array to object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I was looking at some examples but I couldn't find anything solving my problem. I guess problem is trivial but I can't what I am doing wrong. I have such looking simple JSON:

```
{
  "value" : 120,
  "objects" : [
    {
      "object_id" : 1,
      "description" : "First object",
      "flag" : false
    },
    {
     "object_id" : 2,
      "description" : "Second object",
      "flag" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

I created a model for it:

GeneralResponse:

```
public class GeneralResponse {

    public int value;
    public List<NestedObject> objects;

}
```

NestedObject:

```
public class NestedObject {

    public int object_id;
    public String description;
    public boolean flag;

}
```

And I try to parse it like that:

```
GeneralResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(myJSONstring, GeneralResponse.class);
```

And I get an error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 4 column 6 path $.objects[0]
```

Comment: Which version of GSON are you using? I tested with 2.4 and it works as expected.

Comment: Hi, Fisher

@F1sher I am not sure this would help you, why we need to re write for Parsing JSON ? why can't we use any import any json module and can't use it . 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: This thread might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: I apologise everyone. I didn't notice that my NestedObject is an enum with fields and this cause error. Thank you for looking into my matter anyway...

Comment: @F1sher please add this information as answer to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in question code, after the author:

> NestedObject is an enum with fields and this cause error.