# Passing an object through JavaScript with RemoteCommand

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, remotecommand

We're trying to pass an object through primefaces-extensions remoteCommand like this:

```
function dispatchOurObject(ourObject) {
                sendMessageToServer(ourObject);
}
```

This is our remoteCommand tag:

```
        <pe:remoteCommand name="sendMessageToServer" process="@this"
            actionListener="#{ourController.dispatchOurObject}">

            <pe:methodSignature
                parameters="com.package.OurObject" />
            <pe:methodParam name="ourObject">
                <pe:convertJson /> 
            </pe:methodParam>
        </pe:remoteCommand>
```

And last but not least, this is our method in the backing bean:

```
public void dispatchOurObject(OurObject ourObject) {
    //Do some stuff.

}
```

This is the Error we're getting :

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

EDIT: `at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)`

Comment: How does `ourObject` look like? Does it have javascript properties corresponding to java object? In PrimeFaces Extensions examples they are converted to Json format by `JSON.stringify`. Do you have such conversion?

Comment: When we debug the javascript code we can see the right content into ourObject, so it's corresponding to our Java Object.

Comment: Exception says it expects BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 so there should be `{` but there is BEGIN_ARRAY which is`[`. Can you post sent json?

Comment: Additionally check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array).

Comment: @Geinmachi I can't get the JSON because it's done by this : <pe:convertJson />

Comment: So it formats your object to an array (maybe to an array with one element) instead of an object. You cannot see it in web console (F12) during POST request?