# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 13

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I am having Json String in this format.

```
{
    "columns": ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    "columnNames": ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    "isCTemplate": [true, true, true],
    "isCrequired": [false, false, false],
    "columnSizes": [10, 50, -1],
    "columnFormats": ["TEXT", "TEXT", "BOOLEAN(true/false)"],
    "parseErrors": null,
    "data": [
        ["a", "f", "8"],
        ["b", "e", "82"],
        ["c", "d", "822"]
    ],
    "numberOfRecordsInserted": 0,
    "dataErrors": [null, null, null],
    "dataWarnings": ["1", "2", "3"],
    "templateCH": ["One", "Two", "Three"],
    "importS": [null, null, null],
    "formatTypeMap": {
        "array": "TEXT",
        "boolean": "BOOLEAN(true/false)",
        "currency": "CURRENCY"
    },
    "TypeId": "acc",
    "isColumn": [false, false, false],
    "prefixed": [],
    "missed": "tEST",
    "duplicateS": null,
    "global": null,
    "y": 0,
    "s": 1,
    "m": 2,
    "f": 3,
    "vStatus": {
        "vRows": 5,
        "v": 5
    }
}
```

My Jsonhelper Class,

```
public class CopyOfTViewsJSONS {
    @JsonProperty("columns")
    public List<String> columns=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("columnNames")
    public List<String> columnNames=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("isCTemplate")
    public List<String> isCTemplate=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("isCrequired")
    public List<String> isCrequired=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("columnSizes")
    public List<String> columnSizes=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("columnFormats")
    public List<String> columnFormats=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("parseErrors")
    public List<String> parseErrors=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<List<String>> data=new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    @JsonProperty("numberOfRecordsInserted")
    public int numberOfRecordsInserted;

    @JsonProperty("dataErrors")
    public List<String> dataErrors=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("dataWarnings")
    public List<String> dataWarnings=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("templateCH")
    public List<String> templateCH=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("importS")
    public List<String> importS=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("formatTypeMap")
    public HashMap<String, String> formatTypeMap=new HashMap<String, String>();

    @JsonProperty("TypeId")
    public String TypeId;

    @JsonProperty("prefixed")
    public List<String> prefixed=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("missed")
    public List<String> missed=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("duplicateS")
    public List<String> duplicateS=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("global")
    public List<String> global=new ArrayList<String>();

    @JsonProperty("Y")
    public int Y;

    @JsonProperty("s")
    public int s;

    @JsonProperty("m")
    public int m;

    @JsonProperty("f")
    public int f;

    @JsonProperty("vStatus")
    public HashMap<String, String> vStatus=new HashMap<String, String>();


    }
```

And i am trying to assign that json string to a `HashMap<String,CopyOfTViewsJSONS>` this way,

```
HashMap<String,CopyOfTViewsJSONS> mapsss = new Gson().fromJson(tmp, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, CopyOfTViewsJSONS >>(){}.getType());
```

But i am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 13<br />com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 13 Exception.`

I am first time using json with gson library.

Can any one help me in this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try this `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();`

Comment: @Matthew need to add this before assigning to hashmap?

Comment: You would use it in place of `new Gson().fromJson(...` instead `gson.fromJson(tmp, ...`

Comment: Setting it to lenient has helped me in the past but [go to this thread if it doesn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array).

Comment: @Matthew setLenient is undefined for GsonBuilder I am getting

Comment: What version of Gson are you using?

Comment: Would you be able to use the latest [2.6.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.6.2%7Cjar)?

Comment: @Matthew no i cannot change the version.Please help me in resolving..

Comment: Read through this [thread with the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array).

Comment: @Matthew i gone though them..  but theit format is different from mine..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106754/discussion-between-sandy-and-matthew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to deserialize the JSON into a `Map<String, CopyOfTViewsJSONS>`? As far as I can tell from the class and the JSON that you posted, the JSON perfectly represents one instance of the `CopyOfTViewsJSONS` class. You should therefore be able to deserialize it like this:

```
CopyOfTViewsJSONS result = new Gson().fromJson(tmp, CopyOfTViewsJSONS.class);
```

However, there is a slight problem with this, because the `"missed"` property is incorrectly mapped in your class. In your JSON example, `"missed"` is a `String`, but in the class it is a `List<String>`. Changing the class field to a `String` fixes this problem:

```
@JsonProperty("missed")
public String missed;
```

You can then print out some properties of the result to confirm it was deserialized correctly:

```
System.out.println(result.columns);                  // prints [One, Two, Three]
System.out.println(result.numberOfRecordsInserted);  // prints 0
System.out.println(result.TypeId);                   // prints acc
System.out.println(result.vStatus);                  // prints {v=5, vRows=5}
```