# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 - Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to get and Post Data using Retrofit But it Throws Exception **Fsaailurecom.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $**
I tried all possible solutions suggested by the StackOverflow community but still the Problem Exits :(
Any Help..!!

PS: In brwoser and Localhost i can able to get the Correct Json Response for the [API call](http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php) http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php . In postman it returns **This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support**

**API CALL**

```
private void getUsersFromDB() {
        userservice= ApiUtils.getUserservice();
        userservice.getUsers().enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                Log.d("RESULT", "onResponse: --------------------------------SUCCESS");
                List<Result> userresponses = response.body().getResult();
                Log.d("ANS", "Number of movies received: " + userresponses.size());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("RESULT", "onResponse: --------------------------------Failure" +t);

            }
        });


    }
```

**UserModal.java**

```
public class UserModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("user_name")
    @Expose
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("user_password")
    @Expose
    private String userPassword;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

}
```

**UserResponse.java**

```
public class UserResponse {

    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Result> result = null;
    @SerializedName("error_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer errorCode;

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Integer getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    public void setErrorCode(Integer errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
public interface UserService {
    @GET("/get_user.php")
    Call<UserResponse> getUsers();

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/insert_user.php")
    Call<DBResponse> insertUsers(@Field("user_name") String username,
                                 @Field("user_password") String userpassword);
}
```

This is my Json

```
{"result":[{"Users":{"id":"1","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"2","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"3","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"4","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"5","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"6","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"7","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"8","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"9","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"10","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"11","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}},{"Users":{"id":"12","user_name":"raj","user_password":"rajesh123"}}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried List<UserModal> instead of List<Result> into UserResponse?

Comment: @oskarko Yes but no change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Answer (score 1):

Server is returning just a String, not an object. Try to see what is the answer in Fiddler or just create a request in Postman with the same request data to see the answer.

As i can see, in `result` you have a list of objects, object encoded in `User` that return your `UserModal.java`. So, you need to create an intermediar object between `result` and your `UserModal.java`. Something like:

```
public IntermediarUser {
    @SerializedName("User")
    public UserModal user;

    // getter, setter, etc
}
```

If you don't want to do that, check your server implementation for cloud.

Comment: You Right Man In browser I can able to get a Exact JSon Result But in case of PostMan it returns Error Like **This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support** What to do..??

Comment: Hey @Florescu Here is the Link to test in Browser and Postman  [try this ](http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php)

Comment: It works fine in Local Hosting the problems Comes when i move to Clould

Comment: Have you tested [this](http://onesignaldemo.rf.gd/test/get_user.php) link in browser and postman..?? are you got same results..??

Comment: Yes, is the same as you posted into your question.

Comment: Have you tested it On postman...?? For me it returns **This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139172/discussion-between-rajesh-kumar-arumugam-and-florescu-george-ctlin).

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong but it looks like your JSON returns **one** result object which has a list of users rather than a list of results? So you should have a Result pojo with a List property then your user object, I think, should have three strings: id, user_name and user_password. That error nearly always (if not always) refers to an a mismatch in the structure of your pojos/data model and the structure of the JSON.