# Retrofit gson exception

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, retrofit2

If I send id, password to the server it has to give me a `json` but It gives me an error.

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

This is **Retrofit Code**:

```
public void postCheckUser(String id, String password) {
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(url)
            .build();

    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("id",id);
    map.put("password", password);

    webService = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
    Call<PastMemo> call = webService.getPastMain(map);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PastMemo>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PastMemo> call, Response<PastMemo> response) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                title = response.body().getTitle();
                letter= response.body().getLetter();
                date = response.body().getDate();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SignIn Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SignIn Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PastMemo> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SignIn Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the **WebService Code**:

```
public interface WebService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("PastMain")
    Call<PastMemo> getPastMain(
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> user
    );
}
```

This is **PastMemo code**

```
public class PastMemo {

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("letter")
@Expose
private String letter;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getLetter() {
    return letter;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
}
```

EDIT:
This the json which I have to get

```
[
    {
        "title": null,
        "letter": null,
        "date": null
    },
    {
        "title": "a",
        "letter": "b",
        "date": "c"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please post that line at which it is throwing the same exception

Comment: I debugged all the lines to check the error line but It doesn't show up. It only goes to the onFailure() method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception :
**com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path**.

occurs while deserialising, Gson was expecting a JSON object, but found a JSON array. Since it couldn't convert from one to the other, it threw this exception.
Refer this : [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Try this:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("PastMain")
    Call<List<PastMemo>> getPastMain(
            @FieldMap Map<String, String> user
    );
```

Retrofit Code:

```
Call<List<PastMemo>> call = webService.getPastMain(map);
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PastMemo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<PastMemo>> call, Response<List<PastMemo>> response) {

     List<PastMemo> ls = response.body();
     //your implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<PastMemo> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SignIn Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Then What Should I do to solve this problem?? I was looking for a solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This is not the answer. It must be a comment

Comment: Thank you. Maybe some more googling will help me solve this problem

Comment: Instead of catching the object , make provision for list like List<PastMemo>. Or you can first check the response using Postman and accordingly decide the structure.

Comment: Do you mean the json is JSONArray so I need to get the data using list??

Comment: I haven't tried the above code, but it should roughly look like this.