# Failed to load.com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException | Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm trying to display data into `TextViews`. I'm new to `Retrofit` and would appreciate any help and tip(s). The following are what I have so far.

**API Client:**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = ("http://10.1.11.11/");
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**API Service:**

```
public interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("/lara/getprofile.php?id=")
    Call<Profile> getMyProfile(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

**Getter and setter:**

```
public class Profile {
    @SerializedName("PID")
    @Expose
    private String pid;

    @SerializedName("First_Name")
    @Expose
    private String fname;

    @SerializedName("Last_Name")
    @Expose
    private String lname;

    @SerializedName("Team_Lead")
    @Expose
    private String teamlead;

    public Profile(String pid, String fname, String lname, String teamlead) {
        this.pid = pid;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.teamlead = teamlead;
    }


    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getTeamlead() {
        return teamlead;
    }

    public void setTeamlead(String teamlead) {
        this.teamlead = teamlead;
    }
}
```

**Displaying data into TextViews:**

```
  private void getProfile(final String id){
    ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

    Call<Profile> call = apiService.getMyProfile(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Profile>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Profile> call, Response<Profile> response) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Profile p = response.body();

            pid.setText(p.getPid());
            fname.setText(p.getFname());
            lname.setText(p.getLname());
            teamlead.setText(p.getTeamlead());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Profile> call, Throwable t) {
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Failed to load." + t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    });
}
```

**JSON fields that I'm trying to display to TextViews:**

[image: JSON]

**I'm getting the following error message:**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN\_OBJECT but was BEGIN\_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Comment: post json as code not as image

Comment: You are trying to parse json response as object where you json response contains an array ( starts and ends with `[]` ).
I think you have two options.
1. Change your json response to object ( just remove `[]` ).
2. Change your parser to parse json array instead of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong because you are parsing your response As Object for `Profile`  but actually, a response in the array means you need to parse response as an array, replace your API service as bellow also change calling as bellow

```
public interface ApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("/lara/getprofile.php?id=")
    Call<List<Profile>> getMyProfile(@Query("id") String id);
}



private void getProfile(final String id){
  ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
    Call<List<Profile>> call = apiService.getMyProfile(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Profile>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Profile>> call, Response<List<Profile>> response) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
            List<Profile> p = response.body();
            if(p!=null && p.size()>0){
            pid.setText(p.get(0).getPid());
            fname.setText(p.get(0).getFname());
            lname.setText(p.get(0).getLname());
            teamlead.setText(p.get(0).getTeamlead());}
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Profile>> call, Throwable t) {
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePage.this, "Failed to load." + t, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I did to the callback method so far but I'm not able to figure out what's wrong. 

    private void getProfile(final String id){
        ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

        Call<List<Profile>> call = apiService.getMyProfile(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Profile>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Profile>> call, Response<List<Profile>>response) {

                 

            }

Comment: The line  Profile p = response.body(); is the only one that's having an error now. Message: Incompatible types, found: java.util.list

Comment: I got it @Dhaval by using the following code: 

 List<Profile> person = response.body();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    // Can iterate through list and grab Getters from POJO
                    for(Profile p: person){
                        fname.setText(p.getFname().toString());
                        lname.setText(p.getLname().toString());
                    }

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use List Because its array and parse the array of objecct:

```
public interface ApiService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("/lara/getprofile.php?id=")
Call<List<Profile>> getMyProfile(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

Instead:

```
public interface ApiService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@GET("/lara/getprofile.php?id=")
Call<Profile> getMyProfile(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R2R! I'm almost there. Not sure how to display to the TextViews.

    @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Profile>> call, 
              Response<List<Profile>> response) {

                Profile p = response.body();   ---Getting error on this line, incompatible types. Found java.util.List
                psid.setText(p.getPsid());
                fname.setText(p.getFname());
                lname.setText(p.getLname());
                teamlead.setText(p.getTeamlead());
            }

Comment: you have retrive like array...response.get(0).getPsid();....0 is the index       ArrayList<Profiel> profileList=response.body(); if its helpful agree the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure what I'm doing. After updating the Apiservice, I got errors on my callback method so I tried to play with it by setting the value of one of the textviews but nothing's happening when running the app. Here's an update on my callback method:

Comment: private void getProfile(final String id){
        ApiService apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

        Call<List<Profile>> call = apiService.getMyProfile(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Profile>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Profile>> call, Response<List<Profile>>response) {

                psid.setText(id);

            }