# Using Moshi to parse the following JSON

Tags: android, json, moshi

I have the following JSON response from an API endpoint. I have tried using GSON to parse the JSON but there seems to be a bug. Now I am trying to see if I can use Moshi. How can I use Moshi to parse the following JSON object: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZJoS5WetAfjMbjU-_YPbW0EPDJSmKpFk. I have been using the following POJO: for the products class

```
public class ProductsByCategory{

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("permalink")
    @Expose
    private String permalink;
    @SerializedName("date_created")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreated;
    @SerializedName("date_created_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateCreatedGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_modified")
    @Expose
    private String dateModified;
    @SerializedName("date_modified_gmt")
    @Expose
    private String dateModifiedGmt;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("featured")
    @Expose
    private Boolean featured;
    @SerializedName("catalog_visibility")
    @Expose
    private String catalogVisibility;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("short_description")
    @Expose
    private String shortDescription;
    @SerializedName("sku")
    @Expose
    private String sku;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    private String price;
    @SerializedName("regular_price")
    @Expose
    private String regularPrice;
    @SerializedName("sale_price")
    @Expose
    private String salePrice;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFrom;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_from_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleTo;
    @SerializedName("date_on_sale_to_gmt")
    @Expose
    private Object dateOnSaleToGmt;
    @SerializedName("price_html")
    @Expose
    private String priceHtml;
    @SerializedName("on_sale")
    @Expose
    private Boolean onSale;
    @SerializedName("purchasable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean purchasable;
    @SerializedName("total_sales")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalSales;
    @SerializedName("virtual")
    @Expose
    private Boolean virtual;
    @SerializedName("downloadable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean downloadable;
    @SerializedName("downloads")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> downloads = null;
    @SerializedName("download_limit")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadLimit;
    @SerializedName("download_expiry")
    @Expose
    private Integer downloadExpiry;
    @SerializedName("external_url")
    @Expose
    private String externalUrl;
    @SerializedName("button_text")
    @Expose
    private String buttonText;
    @SerializedName("tax_status")
    @Expose
    private String taxStatus;
    @SerializedName("tax_class")
    @Expose
    private String taxClass;
    @SerializedName("manage_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean manageStock;
    @SerializedName("stock_quantity")
    @Expose
    private Integer stockQuantity;
    @SerializedName("in_stock")
    @Expose
    private Boolean inStock;
    @SerializedName("backorders")
    @Expose
    private String backorders;
    @SerializedName("backorders_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordersAllowed;
    @SerializedName("backordered")
    @Expose
    private Boolean backordered;
    @SerializedName("sold_individually")
    @Expose
    private Boolean soldIndividually;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    @Expose
    private String weight;
    @SerializedName("dimensions")
    @Expose
    private Dimensions dimensions;
    @SerializedName("shipping_required")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingRequired;
    @SerializedName("shipping_taxable")
    @Expose
    private Boolean shippingTaxable;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class")
    @Expose
    private String shippingClass;
    @SerializedName("shipping_class_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer shippingClassId;
    @SerializedName("reviews_allowed")
    @Expose
    private Boolean reviewsAllowed;
    @SerializedName("average_rating")
    @Expose
    private String averageRating;
    @SerializedName("rating_count")
    @Expose
    private Integer ratingCount;
    @SerializedName("related_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> relatedIds = null;
    @SerializedName("upsell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> upsellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("cross_sell_ids")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> crossSellIds = null;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer parentId;
    @SerializedName("purchase_note")
    @Expose
    private String purchaseNote;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    @Expose
    private List<Category> categories = null;
    @SerializedName("tags")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> tags = null;
    @SerializedName("images")
    @Expose
    private List<Image> images = null;
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Attribute> attributes = null;
    @SerializedName("default_attributes")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> defaultAttributes = null;
    @SerializedName("variations")
    @Expose
    private List<Integer> variations = null;
    @SerializedName("grouped_products")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> groupedProducts = null;
    @SerializedName("menu_order")
    @Expose
    private Integer menuOrder;
    @SerializedName("meta_data")
    @Expose
    private List<MetaDatum> metaData = null;
    @SerializedName("_links")
    @Expose
    private Links links;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     * 
     */
    public ProductsByCategory() {
    }
}
```

But have been experiencing the following errors : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path or the other way round

My code was the following:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

    String mMessage = response.body().string();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ProductsByCategory items = gson.fromJson(mMessage, ProductsByCategory.class);

            response.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Failed to upload");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        errorMessage(mMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the bug with gson? Gson is pretty stable for the most part unless you are using something like okhttp then it makes sense to use moshi because they are normally packaged together but from independent json parsing gson should be fine.

Comment: @shiredude95 please see the edit above

Answer (score 0):

The bug is not in Gson, but rather your type declaration. The Json presented is of type array, but you have not defined it to be so hence the type mismatch. Redefine your return type to array. This question also deals with a similar issue: [GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

Comment: I did change it to an array and it still gave me problems