# Fetch JSON data using retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit

I want to fetch json from a url https://api.myjson.com/bins/mxcsl/ using retrofit and rxjava.
Sample json is this :

```
{
"data": [
{
  "itemId": "1",
  "desc": "Batcave",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/17.mp3"
},
{
  "itemId": "2",
  "desc": "Fight Club rules",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/2514.mp3"
},
{
  "itemId": "3",
  "desc": "Make an offer",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/47.mp3"
}]}
```

And here is my code : 
Data Model :

```
public class Data {

private String itemId;
private String desc;
private String audio;

public String getItem() {
    return itemId;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public String getAudio() {
    return audio;
}}
```

This is the Interface :

```
public interface RequestInterface {

@GET("/bins/mxcsl/")
Observable<List<Data>> register();
```

}

I'm loading something like this :

```
private void loadJSON() {


    RequestInterface requestInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(RequestInterface.class);

    mCompositeDisposable.add(requestInterface.register()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
}

private void handleResponse(List<Data> androidList) {

    mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>(androidList);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private void handleError(Throwable error) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Error "+error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But Also I'm getting the error **expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT**

I don't know where this is going wrong. Please help.

Comment: Because your json is not `List<Data>`. It's actually an object with the key `data` and that object is `List<Data>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/9598707/9119277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api response is a `JSONObject` which contain a `JSONArray` with key `data`.

Wrap your List of Data with another Model class

```
public class ResponseData {

  @SerializedName("data")
  private List<Data> dataList;

  public List<Data> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
  }

  public void setDataList(List<Data> list) {
    dataList = list;
  }

}
```

Use `ResponseData` class in `RequestInterface`

```
public interface RequestInterface {

  @GET("/bins/mxcsl/")
  Observable<ResponseData> register();

}
```

**Added:**

As your converted Response is `ResponseData` object so your `handleResponse` method parameter would be  `ResponseData` type. In `handleResponse` get your expected list from getter method and set it to `Adapter`.

`handleResponse` method

```
private void handleResponse(ResponseData responseData) {
  if( responseData != null){
     List<Data> dataList = responseData.getDataList();
     mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     if(dataList!= null){
        mAndroidArrayList.addAll(dataList);
     }
     mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList);
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 }
}
```

Comment: My handleResponse is this :
private void handleResponse(List<Data> androidList) {
 
    mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>(androidList);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList); 
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
} 
How to change this ?

Answer (score 3):

Your type

```
Observable<List<Data>> register();
```

is wrong. Because Json's first level is not Array (But object with field `data`, that is array).
You should create class for outer structure

```
public class Outer{
    List<Data> data;
}
```

And specify in retrofit, as observable:

```
@GET("/bins/mxcsl/")
Observable<Outer> register();
```

Comment: My handleResponse is this :
private void handleResponse(List<Data> androidList) {
 
    mAndroidArrayList = new ArrayList<>(androidList);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(mAndroidArrayList); 
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
} 
How to change this ?

Comment: Like this, this will be your method:
private void handleResponse(Outer response) 
inside it you can get list as:
mAndroidArrayList =  response.data 
And everything else will be the same

Answer (score 0):

The error is because Retrofit is expecting a json array to be deserialized as a List

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("/bins/mxcsl/")
    Observable<List<Data>> register();
}
```

But the json response is an object with a field named *data* that is an array

```
{
 "data": [
 {
  "itemId": "1",
  "desc": "Batcave",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/17.mp3"
 },
 {
  "itemId": "2",
  "desc": "Fight Club rules",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/2514.mp3"
 },
 {
  "itemId": "3",
  "desc": "Make an offer",
  "audio": "https://storage.googleapis.com/a/47.mp3"
}]}
```