# gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, android, gson

I am new to gson and getting this error.

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2527 path $.data.batting[0].scores[1].dismissal-by

it is because of the different json reply given by the API.

this is the json reply:

```
 "batting": [
  {
    "scores": [
      {
        "dismissal-by": {
          "name": "CE Rudd",
          "pid": "646213"
        },
        "dismissal": "stumped",
        "SR": 126,
        "6s": 0,
        "4s": 5,
        "B": 34,
        "R": 43,
        "dismissal-info": "st  Rudd b Kerr",
        "batsman": "NE Bolton",
        "pid": "267611"
      },
      {
        "dismissal-by": [
          {
            "name": "M du Preez",
            "pid": "54646"
          }
        ],
        "dismissal": "runout",
        "SR": 112,
        "6s": 0,
        "4s": 4,
        "B": 25,
        "R": 28,
        "dismissal-info": "run out (du Preez)",
        "batsman": "GEB Boyce",
        "pid": "874261"
      },
      {
        "dismissal-by": {
          "name": "LK Bell",
          "pid": "878025"
        },
        "dismissal": "catch",
        "SR": 100,
        "6s": 0,
        "4s": 2,
        "B": 27,
        "R": 27,
        "dismissal-info": "c Bell b Scholfield",
        "batsman": "AE Satterthwaite",
        "pid": "233007"
      },
      {
        "dismissal": "not out",
        "SR": 220,
        "6s": 2,
        "4s": 5,
        "B": 20,
        "R": 44,
        "dismissal-info": "not out",
        "batsman": "H Kaur",
        "pid": "372317"
      },
      {
        "dismissal": "not out",
        "SR": 100,
        "6s": 0,
        "4s": 1,
        "B": 14,
        "R": 14,
        "dismissal-info": "not out",
        "batsman": "E Threlkeld  ",
        "pid": "878035"
      },
      {
        "SR": "",
        "6s": "",
        "4s": "",
        "B": "",
        "R": "",
        "dismissal-info": "",
        "detail": "6 (b 1, w 5)",
        "batsman": "Extras",
        "pid": 0
      }
    ],
    "title": "Lancashire Thunder Innings"
  },
```

getting the error at the 2nd dismissal-by object.

the 1st dismissal-by starts with an object and the second dismissal-by object by an array.

this is the java class for the scores array

```
public class Score__ implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("dismissal-by")
@Expose
private DismissalBy dismissalBy;
@SerializedName("dismissal")
@Expose
private String dismissal;
@SerializedName("SR")
@Expose
private String sR;
@SerializedName("6s")
@Expose
private String _6s;
@SerializedName("4s")
@Expose
private String _4s;
@SerializedName("B")
@Expose
private String b;
@SerializedName("R")
@Expose
private String r;
@SerializedName("dismissal-info")
@Expose
private String dismissalInfo;
@SerializedName("batsman")
@Expose
private String batsman;
@SerializedName("pid")
@Expose
private Integer pid;
@SerializedName("detail")
@Expose
private String detail;

public DismissalBy getDismissalBy() {
    return dismissalBy;
}

public void setDismissalBy(DismissalBy dismissalBy) {
    this.dismissalBy = dismissalBy;
}

public String getDismissal() {
    return dismissal;
}

public void setDismissal(String dismissal) {
    this.dismissal = dismissal;
}

public String getSR() {
    return sR;
}

public void setSR(String sR) {
    this.sR = sR;
}

public String get6s() {
    return _6s;
}

public void set6s(String _6s) {
    this._6s = _6s;
}

public String get4s() {
    return _4s;
}

public void set4s(String _4s) {
    this._4s = _4s;
}

public String getB() {
    return b;
}

public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}

public String getR() {
    return r;
}

public void setR(String r) {
    this.r = r;
}

public String getDismissalInfo() {
    return dismissalInfo;
}

public void setDismissalInfo(String dismissalInfo) {
    this.dismissalInfo = dismissalInfo;
}

public String getBatsman() {
    return batsman;
}

public void setBatsman(String batsman) {
    this.batsman = batsman;
}

public Integer getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(Integer pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(String detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}
```

}

the dismissal-by java class

```
public class DismissalBy implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("pid")
@Expose
private String pid;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(String pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}
```

}

how do i fix this problem ?
any help will be appreciated

Comment: The API that you are using is inconsistent, tell the developer of API to fix it. Although it is possible to work with this API by adding some patches, I do not recommend using an inconsistent API.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Answer (score 2):

in your JSON object, there is a

```
"dismissal-by": {
          "name": "LK Bell",
          "pid": "878025"
        },
```

you cannot use it like this since you declare it as an array it should stay at the same type there for you need to change it to something like

```
  "dismissal-by"":[
    {
          "name": "LK Bell",
          "pid": "878025"
        }
    ]
```

,

to fix this issue you need to parse all JSON manually like

```
Json json = new Json(string);
try{
json.getJsonArray("dismissal-by");
}catch(IllegalStateException e)
{
json.getObject("dismissal-by");  
}
```

Comment: how can i neglect the dismissal-by object an parse the remaining json using gson ?

Comment: @SreyashGaonkar I'm not sure if you can do that

Comment: @SreyashGaonkar you are welcome, but in general you not suppose to handle this because the API is not written in a standard way try to contact the web developer

Comment: the API provider is not ready to change the API response. please suggest me another method to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

that JSON is invalid... therefore the `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`.

it needs to start with a `{` and after `"title": "Lancashire Thunder Innings"`, there is a `}]` missing.

there you can check for yourself: https://jsonlint.com

Comment: the json which I have provided is a part of a larger reply I have only given a small part where m getting the error

Comment: @SreyashGaonkar even if the leading `{` may have been truncated, the missing `}]` is still breaking the syntax; else GSON would not complain and it would not call it a `JsonSyntaxException`. ever tried to validate the whole response with jsonlint?

Comment: yes I put the whole json response its showing valid

Comment: @SreyashGaonkar it reads: expected `BEGIN_OBJECT` but was `BEGIN_ARRAY` at `column 2527` ...which literally translates to: expected `{`, but found `[`. see the question/answers added above; if the JSON is valid, this is likely the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The dismissal-by you are getting is Some time in array format (start with [ and end with ]) while some time it is Json object {} it will be better to resolve it from API developer. Or you can declare it as String and do parsing later where required.

```
public class Score__ implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("dismissal-by")
@Expose
private String dismissalBy;}
```

Comment: i contacted the api developer lets see what he replies

Comment: is there any way where i can neglect the dismissal object and read the remaining json using gson ???

Comment: just try as I mention above it will parse the dismissalBy as String

Comment: then you can parse the dismissalBy where you need like this "Object json = new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
       if (json instanceof JSONObject)
         //you have an object
       else if (json instanceof JSONArray)"