# Stuck on getting JSONArray from a JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON response that looks something like:

[image]

And a Subscription POJO class and inside it, is an Arraylist of the "subscriptionPlans":

**SubscriptionDetails.java**

```
@Expose()
@SerializedName("subscriptionPlans")
public ArrayList<SubscriptionPlans> subscriptionPlans;


public ArrayList<SubscriptionPlans> getSubscriptionPlans() {
    return subscriptionPlans;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SubscriptionDetails{" +
            "subscriptionPlans=" + subscriptionPlans +
            '}';
}
```

**SubscriptionPlans.java**

```
@SerializedName("plan_name")
@Expose
public String planName;

@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
public String description;

@SerializedName("amount")
@Expose
public String amount;

public String getPlanName() {
    return planName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```

I'm using Gson to get the data from the JSON and populate it to the various POJO classes like so:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SubscriptionDetails subscriptionDetails = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject.getJSONArray("subscriptionPlans")), SubscriptionDetails.class);
ArrayList<SubscriptionPlans> subscriptionPlans = subscriptionDetails.getSubscriptionPlans();

String amount = subscriptionPlans.get(0).getAmount();
```

however, I get the error response, 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException:Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line column 2 path $`

What I'm I missing or not doing correct here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass to GSON the entire string, not just `String.valueOf(jsonObject.getJSONArray("subscriptionPlans"))`**:**

```
SubscriptionDetails subscriptionDetails = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jsonObject), SubscriptionDetails.class);
```