# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 123 path $.options in easypost shipment

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, easypost

I am integrating the shipment in my application using easy post API when I use `shipment.create(shipmentMap, EASYPOSTAPIKEY)` it's throwing an error Expected a string but was `BEGIN_OBJECT` at line 1 column 123 path `$.options`.

```java
Map<String, Object> parcelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parcelMap.put("predefined_package", "FlatRateEnvelope");
parcelMap.put("weight", 10);
Parcel parcel = Parcel.create(parcelMap);
Map<String, Object> shipmentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
shipmentMap.put("to_address", toAddress);
shipmentMap.put("from_address", fromAddress);
shipmentMap.put("parcel", parcel);
Shipment shipment = Shipment.create(shipmentMap, EASYPOSTAPIKEY);
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was
> BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 123 path $.options.at
> com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825)
> ~[gson-2.8.5.jar:na]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but annoyingly it's only occuring in production. I narrowed the issue down to Gson failing to parse the Map<String, Object> options; object in the Shipment class. I will create an issue for this in the EasyPost GitHub

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/EasyPost/easypost-java/issues/54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the latest version of easy post client API should fix this.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but already have the latest version of the easy post client api

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of Easy post API but from exception

> options.at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:825) ~[gson-2.8.5.jar]

I could say it is related to GSON.

From my understanding GSON says it needs a String but there was an object.

referred this post for that.
[GSON throwing "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array)

I would ask you to go through the document again and check what you have missed