# Error 400, Bad Request, Json Parse error: Unrecognized token 'agama' : was Expecting ('true','false', or 'null') in Android Retrofit with Spring Boot

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, retrofit2, nested-object

I have this kind of JSON:
**EDITED**

```
{
 "tgl_Lahir": "1960-12-18 00:00:00",
 "nama": "Rahmi P",
 "keterangan": "HIDUP",
 "tempatLahir": "YOGYAKARTA",
 "noPegawai": "010713",
 "golDarah": "0",
 "statusNikah": "0",
  "hubungans": {
            "id": "10"
         },
 "agama": {
            "id_Agama": "1"
          },

 "jeniskelamin": {
            "jenisKelamin": "1"
        }
}
```

I have this interface class:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("http://ipaddress/family/add")
    Call<familylistresponse> addFams(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
                                     @Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                     @Query("id") String id,
//                                     @Field("noPegawai") JSONObject noPegawai,
                                     @Field("agama") JSONObject agama,
                                     @Field("hubungans") JSONObject hubungans,
                                     @Field("jeniskelamin") JSONObject jeniskelamin,
                                     @Field("tgl_Lahir") JSONObject tgl_lahir,
                                     @Field("nama") JSONObject nama,
                                     @Field("keterangan") JSONObject keterangan,
                                     @Field("tempatLahir") JSONObject tempatLahir,
                                     @Field("golDarah") JSONObject goldar,
                                     @Field("statusNikah") JSONObject statusNikah);
```

I want to store my data to database server so I add this method inside my button.setOnClickListener:

```
public void addFamily(String noPegawai, String agama, String hubungan, String jenisKelamins, String tgl_Lahir, String nama, String keterangan, String tempatLahir, String golDarah, String statusNikah){
        String id=null;
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        String tokens = preferences.getString("userToken",null);
        try {
            jsonObject.put("noPegawai", noPegawai);
            jsonObject.put("agama", agama);
            jsonObject.put("hubungans", hubungan);
            jsonObject.put("jeniskelamin", jenisKelamins);
            jsonObject.put("tgl_Lahir", tgl_Lahir);
            jsonObject.put("nama", nama);
            jsonObject.put("keterangan", keterangan);
            jsonObject.put("tempatLahir", tempatLahir);
            jsonObject.put("golDarah", golDarah);
            jsonObject.put("statusNikah", statusNikah);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Call<familylistresponse> call = apiService.addFams("application/json","Bearer " + tokens , id, jsonObject, jsonObject, jsonObject, jsonObject , jsonObject, jsonObject, jsonObject, jsonObject, jsonObject);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<familylistresponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<familylistresponse> call, Response<familylistresponse> response) {
                try {
                    if(response.body()!=null)
                        Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," response message success "+response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(response.errorBody()!=null)
                        Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," response message error "+response.errorBody().string(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Log.e("ERROR: ", response.errorBody().string());
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," Tokens "+tokens,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<familylistresponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

but when I try to post it to the server it shows me this error
[image]

Any ideas? or it's because of my nested son? or my interface's class? Thank you

Comment: Here `"agama": {
            "id_Agama": "1"
          },` is a JsonObject and you are passing it as a string.

Comment: @NensiKasundra so how can I fix it? because at first I use converter in android to generate JSON, and turns out String. And I already wrote this `agamas.setAgama(spAgama.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());` to actually get the Agama objects.

Comment: @Parth so it means I need to convert the string into JSON? but what about I added a header to set the content-type application/JSON

Comment: @XVallerie please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've **SOLVED THE ISSUE**!
I don't know if this will become a solution for future readers or not. But at least it'll help a little bit.

**1. Interface Class**: I just change the form format into @Body type, I think it makes me easier to actually insert the data, you just have to sort your input type value in sequence so that it will automatically be inserted to your server API input format.

```
 @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
        @POST("http://ipaddress/family/add/")
        Call<familylistresponse> addFams(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                         @Body familylistresponse familybody);
```

**2. Nested Objects**: So before, I've tried some solutions that you guys gave to me these days, and thank you for that. But what I did to solve my issue was different. So as you can see that I have nested objects on agamas, hubungans, and jeniskelamin. What did I do? It's just a simple one, like this (Call your "GSON Generate Class") like this :

```
Agama agamas = new Agama();
agamas.setIdAgama(vAgama);
Jeniskelamin jks = new Jeniskelamin();
jks.setJenisKelamin(vJenisk);
Hubungans hubungans = new Hubungans();
hubungans.setId(vHub);
```

After that, you just need to add those variables into your Main Model Class in your Activity :

```
familylistresponse f = new familylistresponse();
  f.setTglLahir(name);
  f.setAgama(agamas);
  f.setHubungan(hubungans);
  etc....
```

**And BOOM! There you go~**
This is an additional TIPS: Make sure your variables on the client's app are the same as you've settled on your database server! :D Ur Welcome ~~
Please vote for this answer if you feel that it is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
"agama":
 {
    "id_Agama": "1"
 }
```

but agama is just a `string` so solve it like this

`"agama":"1"`

Comment: actually, from the database, there are many values stated. It's like 1 is for A value, then 2 is for B value, and etc

Comment: So you have to switch to an object or map...but String won't work here for your need

Comment: At which point it is failed ? During deserialization of the post request or later ?

Comment: on my button save that calls addFamily()... and I did write the Call.enqueue inside the try-catch on JSONObject

Comment: In `addFamily()` agama is still a string...not an object ...is it normal ?

Comment: I set the agama as an JSONObject inside the method

Comment: `public void addFamily(String noPegawai, String agama, `ok but here a string is waiting...

Comment: but before, I also try to change it to JSONObject before I set in inside the method.. but still no result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212356/discussion-between-codescale-and-xvallerie).

Answer (score 0):

set your value like this.

```
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
    try {
      jobj.put("id_Agama", "1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

pass in your request like this.

```
@Field("agama") JSONObject jobj,
```

Answer (score 0):

**interface class:**

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("http://103.82.240.144:1111/WSHRIS/pegawai/family/add")
    Call<familylistresponse> addFams(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,
                                     @Header("Authorization") String auth,
                                     @Query("id") String id,
                                     @Field("noPegawai") boolean noPegawai,
                                     @Field("agama") JSONObject  agama,
                                     @Field("hubungans") JSONObject hubungans,
                                     @Field("jeniskelamin") JSONObject jeniskelamin,
                                     @Field("tgl_Lahir") String tgl_lahir,
                                     @Field("nama") String nama,
                                     @Field("keterangan") String keterangan,
                                     @Field("tempatLahir") String tempatLahir,
                                     @Field("golDarah") String goldar,
                                     @Field("statusNikah") String statusNikah);
```

Pass in argument JSON object in argument

```
    public void addFamily(String noPegawai, String agama, String hubungan, String jenisKelamins, String tgl_Lahir, String nama, String keterangan, String tempatLahir, String golDarah, String statusNikah){
            String id=null;
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
            String tokens = preferences.getString("userToken",null);

 JSONObject agamajsonObject= new JSONObject();
 JSONObject hubungansjsonObject= new JSONObject();
 JSONObject jeniskelaminjsonObject= new JSONObject();

        try {
          agamajsonObject.put("id_Agama", "1");
          hubungansjsonObject.put("id", "10");
          jeniskelaminjsonObject.put("jenisKelamin", "1");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

            Call<familylistresponse> call = apiService.addFams("application/json","Bearer " + tokens , id, true, agamajsonObject, hubungansjsonObject, jeniskelaminjsonObject, tgl_Lahir, nama, keterangan, tempatLahir, golDarah,statusNikah);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<familylistresponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<familylistresponse> call, Response<familylistresponse> response) {
                    try {
                        if(response.body()!=null)
                            Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," response message success "+response.body(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(response.errorBody()!=null)
                            Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," response message error "+response.errorBody().string(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e("ERROR: ", response.errorBody().string());
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(TambahDataKeluarga.this," Tokens "+tokens,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<familylistresponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("ERROR: ", t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: so this one is like I need to do jsonObject.put() for every variable that I want to store? how can I set it to my interface?

Comment: and also, when I try to input the data without agama, hubungan, and jenis kelamin, the error still showing the same message

Comment: "hubungans":, "agama":jeniskelamin do same like above

Comment: I've edited my code above @NensiKasundra , please kindly check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212350/discussion-between-xvallerie-and-nensi-kasundra).